# Uncaught ReferenceError for module, exports and require

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I'm very new to Angular and node and I'm trying to build a simple Single Page Application using the latest version of angular cli.
I had to jump through a bunch of hoops to get it to even compile:

- install angular-builders and browserified packages that are no longer polyfilled and add them to the extra-webpack.config.js
- install node-loader so webpack can read :node scheme
- add certain packages to "allowedCommonJsDependencies" in angular.json to get rid of warnings

Finally I can compile and serve my app to the browser and I'm greeted with the following errors in the console:

```
require chunk loading:34 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at require chunk loading:34:1
    at require chunk loading:39:1
    at require chunk loading:39:1
zone.js:2803 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at zone.js:2803:3
    at zone.js:2803:3
vendor.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at vendor.js:1:1
external node-commonjs "worker_threads":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at external node-commonjs "worker_threads":1:1
    at external node-commonjs "worker_threads":1:1
```

> 

From what I can tell from researching this, is that some packages are using the CommonJS require() method to import stuff while the browser expects ES compliant import statements. But as far as I can tell I have no control over this.
I'm going to include some files that are possibly relevant:

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "oap-erp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
              "mergeRules": {
                "externals": "replace"
              }
            },
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "jsonwebtoken",
              "node-domexception",
              "crypto",
              "http",
              "https",
              "fs",
              "rxjs"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist/oap-erp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "oap-erp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "oap-erp:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
          "options": {
            "sslKey": "../certs/localhost.key",
            "sslCert": "../certs/localhost.crt",
            "ssl": true
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "oap-erp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "oap-erp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^15.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@pnp/nodejs": "^3.10.0",
    "@pnp/sp": "^3.10.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "fs-web": "^1.0.1",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "node-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

**extra-webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    target: "node",
    node: {
        __dirname: false,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.node$/,
            loader: "node-loader",
        },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            fs: require.resolve('fs-web'),
            http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
            https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
            crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
            url: require.resolve('url'),
            stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
            util: require.resolve('util'),
        },
    },
    // externalsPresets: { node: true }
};
```

**ng version output**

```
Angular CLI: 15.0.3
Node: 18.12.1
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 15.0.3
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1500.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.0.3
@angular-devkit/core            15.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.0.3
@schematics/angular             15.0.3
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.8.4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I knew the learning curve was going to be steep, but I'm kind of losing my mind over here =D.

I tried serving my app after a succesfull compile, but this resulted in js errors in console.

Edit: added output of ng version above.

Edit2: I tried using Babel in conjunction with webpack to transpile to es modules cf.: [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/transpile-es-modules-with-webpack-node-js/). But that didn't seem to change anything. I was under the impression that by implementing this any cjs modules would be translated by Babel to es modules but either I'm mistaken or I did it wrong, both very possible..

Comment: What is your node version ? You need v 18 or later: https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I can only check it at work. I've updated the question with the output of ng version. Node is version 18.12.1.

Comment: Here's hoping a comment bumps this and that is acceptable...
Does anything else come to mind @LoannDelgado?